# Creating an SDK library using Feign

Tags: java, spring, sdk, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm interested in using Feign to create an SDK library for a Spring based client to a Spring Boot restful service.

It seems like the standard Feign use case is a service exposing an API jar instrumented with Feign annotations, and then a client service configuring an OpenFeign client which implements the API.

However, I want to standardize how clients use Hystrix, and are configured, and don't want the client to have a direct dependency on the Feign library. I would prefer to bundle this logic into an SDK and have it abstracted away.

Is this possible with OpenFeign?

How do you get around the package scanning from a main class to find interfaces if the sdk is a pure library, without Main?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you come to a solution?

Comment: I never received a experienced answer; this was a while ago and I didn't get to production with my implementation, but I believe I went ahead and created an SDK using plain OpenFeign (without any direct spring integrations). The Library itself created and used interfaces (matching my service side controllers) annotated for Feign, and manually configured Feign with the proper info.

The benefit was that clients didn't need any direct spring nor feign related dependencies, and all clients could use this generic SDK without having to duplicate code throughout the system.